# Reading data from an API

Tags: java, json, optimization, csv

I have written a function to read some data from an external API. What my function does is , it calls that API while reading a file from the disk. I want to optimize my code for large size of a file (35000 records). Could you please suggest me on this.

Following is my code.

```
public void readCSVFile() {

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFileName()));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


            String[] splitLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            String campaign = splitLine[0];
            String adGroup =  splitLine[1];
            String url = splitLine[2];              
            long searchCount = getSearchCount(url);             

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(campaign + ",");
            sb.append(adGroup + ",");               
            sb.append(searchCount + ",");               
            writeToFile(sb, getNewFileName());

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private long getSearchCount(String url) {
    long recordCount = 0;
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
                "api.com/querysearch?q="
                        + url);
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;

        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser()
                        .parse(output);
                JSONObject result = (JSONObject) json.get("result");
                recordCount = (long) result.get("count");
                System.out.println(url + "=" + recordCount);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return recordCount;

}
```

Comment: Your bottleneck is definitely going to be your HTTP stuff.  I would to optimize this.  Maybe not shut down connections or get bulk results if possible.

Comment: Yes problem is there. Issue is , I have to call this API with a GET parameter which comes from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since remote calls are slower than local disk access, you'll want to in some way parallelize or batch your remote calls. If you can't make batch calls to the remote API, but it allows multiple concurrent reads, then perhaps you want to use something like a thread pool to make the remote calls:

```
public void readCSVFile() {
    // exception handling ignored for space
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFileName()));
    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        final String[] splitLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        futures.add(pool.submit(new Callable<String> {
            public String call() {
                long searchCount = getSearchCount(splitLine[2]);
                return new StringBuilder()
                    .append(splitLine[0]+ ",")
                    .append(splitLine[1]+ ",")
                    .append(searchCount + ",")
                    .toString();
            }
        }));
    }

    for (Future<String> fs: futures) {
        writeToFile(fs.get(), getNewFileName());
    }

    pool.shutdown();
}
```

Ideally, though, you'd really want to make a single batch read from the remote API if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. BTW I am unable to make a single batch read. but multiple concurrent reads are allowed.